# Selecting required element from a list in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a var called 'data'.

print(data) produces follows:

```
 List (1 element)
    0: List (5 elements)
    0: [105.20013400000003,20.48699599999997]
    1: [105.73228,20.48699599999997]
    2: [105.73228,21.018092000000017]
    3: [105.20013400000003,21.018092000000017]
    4: [105.20013400000003,20.48699599999997]
```

How can I select the first element i.e., [105.20013400000003,20.48699599999997] from the data?

Comment: What is this `print()` function? The only `print()` function I'm aware of is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print, which "Opens the Print Dialog to print the current document" and is "Not part of any standard". The function you're calling appears to be different.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your output is just poorly indented and that lines 2-7 are actually elements of the inner `List`.

If so, you should be able to access the item you seek with:

```
var theItemISeek = data[0][0];
```

Comment: However, I got error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    in <global>